# Windows Scheduled Task, Detecting Failure Programmatically

Tags: windows, scripting, scheduled-tasks

I'd like to develop a monitor to detect failed scheduled tasks and tasks that have run for over 'x' minutes. I'm looking for ideas to probe status of tasks and detect a failure code (or receive a status of running). I'd also like to verify the "stop running after 'x' hours" setting.

Answer (score 1):

Have the scheduled task log its start time, end time, and end status in a database. All you need to do is query for the latest entries in the start and end tables to know the current status. As a bonus it gives you a history.

Comment: Your answer is a fantastic response to the question behind the question. I'd still like to see if there's any wisdom out there as to how I can build it around existing scheduled tasks that don't necessarily lend themselves well to a db insert.

Comment: @Dave P: so you have an existing scheduled task that you can't modify? You can always write a wrapper program that does the DB insert, starts the other .exe and waits for it to finish, then writes another DB entry with the result.

Comment: Ah yes, I can do that -- I already have function at my disposal. Thanks again!